# Non trivial results in graph theory/combinatorics coming from number theory

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

Are there any non-trivial results in graph theory that can be deduced from number theory or arithmetic geometry?

I am not looking for expander graphs or applications however I am looking for situations combinatorics inherent in number theory can be transferred to graph theoretic settings in very general terms.

Comment: I know the inverse: you can use graph theory to prove the Schur Theorem: Let $n \in \mathbb{Z},\; n > 1$. Then there exists a prime $p_0$ s.t for every prime $p \geq p_0$, $x^n + y^n \equiv z^n (mod\;p)$ has a non-trivial integer solution i.e a solution where $x,y,x \not\equiv 0 (mod\;p)$. https://amininima.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/fermats-last-theorem-mod-p/

Comment: @Maffred feel free to elaborate below.

Comment: It just says that Fermat's Last Theorem is false in $\mathbb Z_p$ if you pick sufficiently large $p$'s. You can read the link, it is very well explained!

Comment: In this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3376 the authors use  3-term arithmetic progressions and related number theoretical results to obtain a bound on a certain edge coloring.